# Subset of a basis for a normed vector space cannot be Cauchy?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, schauder-basis, linear-independence

In class, we showed that $e_n \in l^p$ converges weakly but not strongly for $p \in (1,\infty)$ and that $\sin(2\pi nx) \in L^2([0,1])$ converges weakly but not strongly. I was wondering if basis elements cannot converge strongly because if they do they are somehow not linearly independent?

I know that these are Schauder bases vs. Hamel bases for the respective spaces, but don't have a good intuition for whether that should make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a handy fact (c.f. Diestel, *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*, pg. 36): a sequence of non-zero vectors $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is a basic sequence (a basis of its closed linear span) if and only if there is a $K>0$ so that for any choice of scalars $(a_n)$ and integers $m<n$
$$
\biggl\Vert \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i\biggl\Vert\le K\biggl\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i\Biggl\Vert.
$$

This easily implies that a normalized basic sequence cannot be Cauchy.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that a sequence consisting of linearly independent vectors is convergent and the norms are bounded away from $ 0.$ For example let $e_n$ form an orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}.$ Then the sequence $$ f_n=e_1+{1\over n}e_n$$ is convergent to $e_1$ and is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

A Schauder basis can converge in norm to $0$.  In fact, for any Schauder basis $u_n$,
$u_n/(n \|u_n\|)$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

If $(e_n)$ is a Schauder basis so is $(c_ne_n)$ for any sequence of positive numbers $(c_n)$. This new Schauder basis can converge strongly to $0$. An orthonormal basis cannto converge in norm. Indeed if $(e_i)$ is an orthonormal basis then $\|e_i-e_j\|=\sqrt 2$ for $i \neq j$, so $(e_i)$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Can you explain why an orthonormal basis cannot converge in norm? Doesn't Ryszard Szwarc's answer give an example of one that does?

Comment: @user02468 No, the example there is not an orthonormal basis. I have edited my answer to show why an  orthonormal basis cannot converge in the norm.